Match text, also match text when enclosed with listed neighbours
I am working on multi-replacement tool and need to replace name of OBJECT_TYPE to different variants.
I have several instances of such name and need to replace it only when relevant, so the rule is to have it solo, or with _POST or _TEMP afterwards. Can have an extension of .ddl or .sql. Can have a prefix Stage_ or CORE_ as well.
I have come up with this regex, but I is not capturing all I need.
\b(?!Stage_|CORE_)(OBJECT_TYPE)(?=_POST|_TEMP|.ddl|.sql|\b)
Here is the regex demo.
The first 6 lines should be matched and should match the OBJECT_TYPE only, the rest should not be captured.
OBJECT_TYPE.sql
OBJECT_TYPE_POST.sql
Stage_OBJECT_TYPE.sql
AUX_DB.OBJECT_TYPE.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_OBJECT_TYPE_TEMP.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.ddl
----
OBJECT_TYPE_ID
CR_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.sql
REST_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.sql
FLOW_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.sql
Stage_CR_OBJECT_TYPE.sql
Stage_REST_OBJECT_TYPE.sql
Stage_FLOW_OBJECT_TYPE.sql
AUX_DB.CR_OBJECT_TYPE.ddl
AUX_DB.REST_OBJECT_TYPE.ddl
AUX_DB.FLOW_OBJECT_TYPE.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_CR_OBJECT_TYPE_TEMP.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_REST_OBJECT_TYPE_TEMP.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_FLOW_OBJECT_TYPE_TEMP.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_CR_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_REST_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.ddl
CORE_DB.CORE_FLOW_OBJECT_TYPE_POST.ddl


Something like (?<=Stage_|CORE_|\b)OBJECT_TYPE(?=(?:_POST|_TEMP)?\.(?:dd|sq)l\b)? https://regex101.com/r/CMnX69/2?

I suggest using
(?<=Stage_|CORE_|\b)OBJECT_TYPE(?=(?:_POST|_TEMP)?\.(?:dd|sq)l\b)

See the regex demo.
Details:

(?<=Stage_|CORE_|\b) - immediately to the left, there should be either Stage_, CORE_ or a word boundary
OBJECT_TYPE - a string that you need to find
(?=(?:_POST|_TEMP)?\.(?:dd|sq)l\b) - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be

(?:_POST|_TEMP)? - an optional occurrence of _POST or _TEMP
\. - a dot
(?:dd|sq)l - dd or sq followed with l
\b - a word boundary.



